# converting relational database model to core data model

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, entity-relationship

I am new to the Core data and I am a bit confused about how to store a part of the object in another entity...

[image: I have two entities: one for locations and the other one for the recently visited or searched]

I have only list of location to be inserted to the "Locations" entity and later recently visited place will be stored...

my question is that can I load Locations entity without providing "RecentlySearched" attribute (relationship inverse)

if not how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is marked as "optional" (which is the default in the Core Data
Model editor) then you don't have to provide a value.

The value of that property will be `nil` until you establish a relationship to a
"RecentSearch" object.